# Bash to clear historic content folders

Tags: bash, shell-script

I require a bash script to keep the most recent 'date_YYYY-MM-DD_HHMMSS' directory, removing others

The directory structure is as follows.  The directories in tags are variable and will change, i.e 'ENVIRONMENT', could be production, staging, development.  Specifically in advance I will not know 'productname'

```
/home/'USER'/'ENVIRONMENT'/Content/'productname'/'date_YYYY-MM-DD_HHMMSS'
```

I've tried

```
ls -t  .\directory | tail -n +1
```

and

```
find .\directory type f -mtime +1
```

(this was during a moment of madness where I was happy to only keep the last days worth of content)

and

```
find . -maxdepth 6 -mindepth 5 -type f -printf '%f\n'
```

So for example, if i had the following

```
/home/USER1/production/Content/productname1/date_20151009_120000
/home/USER1/production/Content/productname1/date_20151010_120000
/home/USER1/production/Content/productname2/date_20151009_120000
/home/USER1/production/Content/productname2/date_20151010_120000
/home/USER1/production/Content/productname1/date_20151009_120000
/home/USER1/production/Content/productname1/date_20151010_120000
/home/USER1/staging/Content/productname2/date_20151009_120000
/home/USER1/staging/Content/productname2/date_20151010_120000
```

I would keep

```
/home/USER1/production/Content/productname1/date_20151010_120000
/home/USER1/production/Content/productname2/date_20151010_120000
/home/USER1/staging/Content/productname2/date_20151010_120000
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify: the most recent directory among which? The most recent `/home/USER/XXX`? `/home/USER/XXX/Content/`? The most recent under each `productname`? Ideally, show us some examples and the result you expect.

Comment: most recent 'date' directory.  first line, right there.  I've updated for clarity.  you're assumption was correct.

Comment: Yes, and most recent among what? Most recent in `environment`? Most recent in `productname`? Most recent overall? Should only one directory be kept or do you, for example, need the most recent dirs from each of the different `ENVIRONMENT` or `USER` values? Also, should we take the time from the directory's name or from its timestamp?

Comment: I see what you mean, most recent in their own sub dir.  I will update again.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `awk` and `xargs` to achieve this,

```
sort -r directories | awk -F/ 'cache[$3, $4, $6]++' | xargs -L1 rm -rf
```

`directories` is just a file containing all your directories, `sort -r directories` could easily be replaced by a pipeline (e.g. `printf "%s\n" /home/*/*/Content/*/* | sort -r`).

`sort -r` puts the directories to keep 'toward the top' of the list (it uses the fact that your dates can be compared lexicographically, if they weren't you'd have to parse them properly first). Finally `awk` does the bookeeping, the first time it sees a (`user`, `environment`, `product`) it doesn't print it, all the following occurrences get printed. This generates a list of directories to delete, which then gets deleted thanks to `xargs`/`rm`.

Note: if your filenames/directories contains spaces or 'weird' characters it won't quite work so you'll have to modify the command.

---

What does `awk -F/ 'cache[$3, $4, $6]++'` do? First it splits the input lines on `/`. Then for each input line it checks if the tuple containing the 3rd, 4th, and 6th values are present in the `cache` associative array. The first time a tuple is seen it's not in the array, so `cache[$3, $4, $6]` returns `0` hence the line gets dropped, the `++` then sets `cache[$3, $4, $6]` to `1`. The next times a tuple is seen `cache[$3, $4, $6]` returns something `> 0`, which means that the line gets printed.

Here's a simple worked example:

```
$ cat example
a,c,0
a,a,2
c,a,0
a,b,2
b,a,2
a,b,0
c,a,1
b,b,0
a,b,1
a,a,1
a,a,0
b,a,1
b,c,2
b,b,2
b,c,1
a,c,1
c,c,1
$ awk -F, 'cache[$1, $2]++' example
a,b,0
c,a,1
a,b,1
a,a,1
a,a,0
b,a,1
b,b,2
b,c,1
a,c,1
$ fgrep a,b example
a,b,2
a,b,0
a,b,1
$
```

Notice how the `a,b,2` line got dropped while `a,b,0` and `a,b,1` didn't. Using an associative array and the `++` operator is a pretty common pattern in `awk`, for instance see [43. Remove duplicate, nonconsecutive lines](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-two/).

Comment: please can you explain 'cache[$3, $4, $6]++' thank you

Comment: @Gaz: added some explanation about how the `awk` call works; it might still be confusing if you're not familiar with `awk` (if so <http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html> is a good resource to get started).

Comment: Thank you. However the AWK grabs the product directory too.  It was getting the /home/environment/ but i got around that by adding the first and second value.